# Similar stotram

Tags: shiva, stotra

In vyankatesh stotra the following is mentioned:

> देवीदास विनवी श्रोतयां चतुरां । प्रार्थनाशतक पठण करा । जावया
> मोक्षाचिया मंदिरा । कांही न लागती सायास ॥ १०६ ॥ एकाग्रचित्ते एकांतीं ।
> अनुष्ठान कीजे मध्यरातीं । बैसोनिया स्वस्थचित्तीं । प्रत्यक्ष मूर्ति
> प्रगटेल ॥

I.e. completing the 100th recitation in the midnight with calm mind enables to see lord 'vyankatesh'.

My question is, is there any similar stotra or something with the same intention of seeing god but for shiva?

Comment: Similar stotra for Saraswati.. too..  
 Please provide for all Trideva/Tridevi.. 

Comment: in which language is this bdw?

Comment: Written by Devidas rushi in Marathi. Although there is also a sanskrit version of the stotra.